# Triangulate faces while preserving custom data in CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal

I have a Polyhedron that uses a custom `Polyhedron_items_ 3` class to add custom data to the faces of the structure. For example:

```cpp
    typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
    typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point_3;
    typedef Kernel::Vector_3 Vector_3;
    typedef Kernel::Plane_3 Plane_3;

    template <class Refs, class Traits>
    struct TFace : public CGAL::Polyhedron_items_3::Face_wrapper<Refs,Traits>::Face {
        std::array<double, 8> my_data;

        TFace() {}
        TFace(const Plane_3& p) : CGAL::Polyhedron_items_3::Face_wrapper<Refs,Traits>::Face(p) {}
    };

    struct CustomPolyhedronItems : public CGAL::Polyhedron_items_3 {
        template <class Refs, class Traits>
        struct Face_wrapper
        {
            typedef typename Traits::Plane_3 Plane;
            typedef TFace<Refs, Plane> Face;
        };
    };

    typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel, CustomPolyhedronItems> Polyhedron;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Polyhedron>::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Polyhedron>::face_descriptor face_descriptor;
```

This works, and allows me to assign custom data (the `my_data` array above) to each face of a Polyhedron.

However, an operation like `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_faces` will generate new faces. Upon testing, it seems that the newly generated faces do not copy over the data from the face that was split, so `my_data` is not preserved.

To test, I created a simple cube (6 quads) with custom data on every face, ran it through `triangulate_faces`, and checked the custom data. Half of the triangles retained the original data, the other half were all zeroed.

Is it possible to tell `triangulate_faces` to copy my custom data when generating new faces? E.g. if a quad is converted into two triangles, then those triangles should have the same data as the original quad.

*Also*, if it is possible, would it also be possible to accomplish something similar with `corefine_and_compute_union` or something like a remesh operation?

EDIT:

In case that wasn't clear, here's a quick illustration of the problem using normals in place of `my_data`. Half of the triangles have correct normals, but the other half are wrong since they're zeroed:

[image: screenshot of cube exported from CGAL and imported into blender]

Obviously, in the case of normals I can just recalculate them. But for my custom data, that's not possible. I need to make sure I preserve it when triangulating (and corefine union)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [Triangle Visitor](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/classPMPTriangulateFaceVisitor.html). Unfortunately, I did that a couple of months ago and I don't remember everything. Note that my triangle mesh has not only face colors properties, but also face scalars.

```cpp
struct TriangulateVisitor : 
  public PMP::Triangulate_faces::Default_visitor<EMesh3>
{
  void before_subface_creations(face_descriptor fsplit) {
    *ofaceindex = fsplit;
  }

  void after_subface_created(face_descriptor fnew) {
    (*fmap).insert(std::make_pair(fnew, *ofaceindex));
  }
  
  TriangulateVisitor()
    : fmap(new MapBetweenFaces()),
      ofaceindex(new face_descriptor())
  {}
  
  std::shared_ptr<MapBetweenFaces> fmap;
  std::shared_ptr<face_descriptor> ofaceindex;
};
```

where

`typedef std::map<face_descriptor, face_descriptor> MapBetweenFaces;`

and

```cpp
void triangulateMesh(EMesh3& mesh) {
  MaybeFcolorMap fcolormap_ = 
    copy_prop<face_descriptor, std::string, EK>(mesh, "f:color");
  const bool hasFcolors = fcolormap_.second;
  MaybeFscalarMap fscalarmap_ = 
    copy_prop<face_descriptor, double, EK>(mesh, "f:scalar");
  const bool hasFscalars = fscalarmap_.second;
  removeProperties(mesh, {"v:normal"});
  TriangulateVisitor vis;
  const bool success = 
    PMP::triangulate_faces(mesh, CGAL::parameters::visitor(vis));
  if(!success) {
    Rcpp::stop("Triangulation has failed.");
  }
  if(hasFcolors) {
    MapBetweenFaces fmap = *(vis.fmap);
    Fcolors_map fcolors = 
      mesh.add_property_map<face_descriptor, std::string>(
        "f:color", ""
      ).first;
    for(EMesh3::Face_index fi: mesh.faces()) {
      fcolors[fi] = fcolormap_.first[fmap[fi]];
    }
  }
  if(hasFscalars) {
    MapBetweenFaces fmap = *(vis.fmap);
    Fscalars_map fscalars = 
      mesh.add_property_map<face_descriptor, double>(
        "f:scalar", nan("")
      ).first;
    for(EMesh3::Face_index fi: mesh.faces()) {
      fscalars[fi] = fscalarmap_.first[fmap[fi]];
    }
  }
}
```

Say me whether this is clear.

Comment: In addition you can also look into CGAL's code itself to find usages of this visitor. [Here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Polyhedron/demo/Polyhedron/Plugins/PMP/Isotropic_remeshing_plugin.cpp#L181) is one of these usages, for example.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the answer from Stéphane Laurent:

> Also, if it is possible, would it also be possible to accomplish something similar with corefine_and_compute_union or something like a remesh operation?

PMP's Boolean operations functions have a similar visitor mechanism:

[Here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/classPMPCorefinementVisitor.html) is the concept describing what your visitor must provide to be used in functions such as [PMP::corefine_and_compute_boolean_operations()](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html#gaaeb559e2f901b418ddd563e8aace83eb) or [PMP::clip()](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html#ga5dc9e7acf8433235adc7b91ac93a7d42).

As in my other comment, I would advise searching the CGAL code base for usages of these functions with a visitor, to have an example.